# Serve static web content and a REST API via Spring Web MVC

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-web

**Important note:** I am looking for a working version and not some code snippets. Please undo the duplicate, because I can't do anything with the answer from the other thread **(Please read the second part of my question - unrelated to resources)**.

I want to create a Spring application:

- That serves an Angular application (as a JSP) with styles etc.
- That also provides the REST API for the application

Questions:

- How do I achieve a co-existance of the JSP and the REST api?
- Do I have to forward to the index.jsp/style.css etc or do I have to install resource handlers?

My project structure:

[image]

My Code:

ApplicationLoader.java

```
package com.stackoverflow.testapp.configuration;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer;

public class ApplicationLoader extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{};
    }

    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{ApplicationConfiguration.class};
    }

    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[]{"/"};
    }
}
```

ApplicationConfiguration.java

```
package com.stackoverflow.testapp.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.stackoverflow.testapp")
public class ApplicationConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewresolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewresolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewresolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/");
        viewresolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewresolver;
    }
}
```

DataController.java

```
package com.stackoverflow.testapp.controllers;

import com.stackoverflow.testapp.models.Data;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@RestController
public class DataController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/singledata", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public Data singledata() {
        Data singledata = new Data();
        return singledata;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/api/multipledata", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<Data> index() {
        List<Data> multipledata = new ArrayList<Data>();
        multipledata.add(new Data());
        multipledata.add(new Data());
        multipledata.add(new Data());
        return multipledata;
    }
}
```

Data.java

package com.stackoverflow.testapp.models;

```
public class Data {
    public String getData() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }
}
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
         pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Testapp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css">
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
         xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>testapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Try to put the static content into /src/mein/resources/static and omit the static while linking to them. This would be the place for static files in spring boot.

Comment: Can you give me more information? I am using the application in a Tomcat environment, but that shouldn't matter. Do you add src/main/resources/static as a ressource to the resource registry?